# Heroku Cedar: how to stop using WEBrick

Tags: heroku

In my Gemfile I have:

```
gem 'thin'
```

But when I push my application to Heroku Cedar, WEBrick is still used ("Booting WEBrick" in logs).

Where might be a problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You just need to create a `Procfile` and add the following line:

```
web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT thin -e $RACK_ENV
```

Push that to Heroku and you'll be all set.

Comment: Use

```web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT thin -e $RACK_ENV```

so that it works for staging servers as well.